# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel but working with Postman / CURL

Tags: c#, ssl

I'm desperately trying to communicate with a server using .NET.

- OS : Windows 10 version 1903
- Framework : 4.7.2
- TLS version of the website : TLS1.2 according to Google Chrome Security Tab
- I tried to bypass server ssl validation by adding ServerCertificateValidationCallback method set to true by default, but I agree, this is not something to do, it was only done for the purpose of the test.
- cipher used is this one, according to Chrome :  TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_256_GCM.
- as @mjwillis mentioned in the comments, ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=oauth2-apiii.e-i.com and learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/… suggests they should have TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in common.

My code is relatively simple, I'm using latest httpClient class from .NET Core with Framework 4.7.2 (Windows 10 version 1903) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://oauth2-apiii.e-i.com"))
                {
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "*/*");
                    
                    var contentList = new List<string>();
                    contentList.Add($"grant_type={Uri.EscapeDataString("authorization_code")}");
                    contentList.Add($"code={Uri.EscapeDataString("a")}");
                    contentList.Add($"scope={Uri.EscapeDataString("b")}");
                    contentList.Add($"client_id={Uri.EscapeDataString("c")}");
                    contentList.Add($"code_verifier={Uri.EscapeDataString("d")}");
                    request.Content = new StringContent(string.Join("&", contentList));
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    HttpContent httpContent = response.Content;
                    string test = httpContent.ToString();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I only get the following error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I tried others methods (HttpRequest, RestSharp) but it still doesnt work.

I tried with cURL and Postman and the result is OK, I get the correct result from the server.

How can it be possible that cURL/Postman manage to send requests to this URL whereas .NET cannot ?

EDIT:

Here is the Fiddler .NET tunnel trace :

[[image: Fiddler .NET tunnel trace1]

And here is the Fiddler Postman tunnel trace :

[[image: Fiddler Postman tunnel trace]

I can't see an obvious difference, it seems the cipher used is the same on both sides : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

EDIT 2 : Interesting fact : Neither Internet Explorer nor Microsoft Edge (not Chromium) are able to access the URL : https://oauth2-apiii.e-i.com/sandbox/cic/oauth2 whereas Firefox, Edge Chromium and Chrome have no difficulties.

I suppose the problem is probably linked.

Comment: what version of TLS is the service using?

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of .NET?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 version 1903 with Framework 4.7.2, the service is using TLS 1.2 according to Google Chrome Security Tab (F12) after entering URL https://oauth2-apiii.e-i.com

Comment: What happens if you comment out `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`?

Comment: When I comment out this line, the error remains the same unfortunately. A simpler code to test it out woud be this :

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            byte[] tes2t = new WebClient().DownloadData("https://oauth2-apiii.e-i.com");
            string strTest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tes2t);

Is this code working for you?

Comment: Use sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare Postman headers to your c# headers.  There is a different in the default headers.  Make sure your c# is using same headers as postman.

Comment: Needed to override `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` at all is a major red flag. What cipher is the server using?

Comment: I agree with you, we should NEVER use this line, it was just a test to be sure I could bypass the SSL / TLS check on client side. The cipher the server is using is this one, if I refer to what Chrome says about it : 

 TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_256_GCM.

Comment: thanks @jdweng I'll try to differentiate what Postman does from .NET according to Fiddler / Wireshark, this may be the best option

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=oauth2-apiii.e-i.com and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1607 suggests they should have TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in common. So it should work.

Comment: Fiddler has a nice feature that when Postman passes SSL/TLS will give encryption mode that was used.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng Postman has that feature too now (I believe this is very recent). And Postman says it used this cipher : 
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 with TLS1.2

Comment: What does c# say for same (use fiddler)?  You code should work because you have TLS1.2 specified in code.  You may need a registry change to get Windows to use Net setting.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: I tried to force DisableUsingServicePointManagerSecurityProtocols to false and DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto to false in the appSettings of the app.config file, but it doesnt change anything. I can't find my framework version under the registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework I should have 4.7.2 here but it stops at 4.5

Comment: It appears Internet Explorer and Edge (not chromium) cannot access the website https://oauth2-apiii.e-i.com/sandbox/cic/oauth2 for the same reasons. That may be linked.

Comment: @Thordax don't try to force anything, you're making things worse. Neither .NET Framework 4.7.2 nor TLS1.2 are broken. You shouldn't even have the line `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` as .NET 4.7 on Windows 10 will pick the best available encryption from the OS settings. That's TLS1.2 now, TLS1.3 when it becomes available

Comment: Good to know @PanagiotisKanavos , don't worry, this kind of "forcing" from my code is just for test purpose, in order to try and make things work. I'll never put such a code in production

Comment: @Thordax but now you have no idea why Edge doesn't work. And IE means nothing - IE and Edge have nothing in common, while HttpClient is unrelated to either

Comment: I don't but I didn't have the meaning before nonetheless. I suppose both of this browsers are using Microsoft .NET Framework

Comment: Neither of them does. Fiddler does though and *it* throws a 504 complaining about a malformed response. When trying to access `https://oauth2-apiii.e-i.com/sandbox/cic/oauth2` there's an exception with inner exceptions that eventually complained about a malformed response too

Comment: Thanks for you answer, so maybe I could face the same kind of malformed response in my c# code and won't be able to do anything about that? If so, how could I be able to avoid this malformed answer and get a proper one, as Postman or cURL can ?

Comment: By the way, @PanagiotisKanavos the 504 error is logic if you try to decrypt HTTPS with Fiddler, this test is not userful here, we will get a 504 for every browser, including Chrome

Comment: @Thordax Hi I have same issue, did you find any solution to solve this problem?